# Xcode6: How to copy the constrains for anyWidth any Height from other size classes?

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I am working on storyboard with  `anyWidth`   `anyHeight`  constraints, i copied a storyboard scene from another sample poc project which has below auto layout constrain for 47 occurrences in the particular storyboard scene

```
/variation> ="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact">
```

How to change this auto layout constrains to  `anyWidth`   `anyHeight`  inside my storyboard file.

I followed this link but don't how to change the "heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact" to  `anyWidth`   `anyHeight` .

[Xcode6: Is there any easy way to copy constrains between size classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706575/xcode6-is-there-any-easy-way-to-copy-constrains-between-size-classes)